# Start/stop thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I can't find any working solution to stopping/resuming a thread when locking/unlocking a device, can anyone help, or tell me where I can find how to do it? I need stop the thread when the phone is locked and start it again when the phone is unlocked.

Comment: Do you already have the code to listen for the lock/unlock event?

Comment: yes, but i not sure that it's correct, can you give a link, or example of source how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Java operates on a cooperative interrupt model for stopping threads.  That means you can't simply stop a thread mid-execution without cooperation from the thread itself.  If you want to stop a thread the client can call Thread.interrupt() method to request the thread stop:

```
public class SomeBackgroundProcess implements Runnable {

    Thread backgroundThread;

    public void start() {
       if( backgroundThread == null ) {
          backgroundThread = new Thread( this );
          backgroundThread.start();
       }
    }

    public void stop() {
       if( backgroundThread != null ) {
          backgroundThread.interrupt();
       }
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
           Log.i("Thread starting.");
           while( !backgroundThread.interrupted() ) {
              doSomething();
           }
           Log.i("Thread stopping.");
        } catch( InterruptedException ex ) {
           // important you respond to the InterruptedException and stop processing 
           // when its thrown!  Notice this is outside the while loop.
           Log.i("Thread shutting down as it was requested to stop.");
        } finally {
           backgroundThread = null;
        }
    }
```

The important part of threading is that you don't swallow InterruptedException and instead stop your thread's loop and shutdown because you only get this exception if a client has request the thread interrupt itself.

So you simply need to hook up the SomeBackgroundProcess.start() to the event for unlock, and hook up the SomeBackgroundProcess.stop() to the lock event.

Comment: It's good, but work only without if( backgroundThread == null ), but thread crush if go to phone menu (hid app and then open again)

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say other than you had to remove if( backgroundThread == null).  It could be a race condition where the thread hasn't shutdown before you hit the phone menu so the thread is dying, but it hasn't reached the finally statement.  Add Log statements in start/stop and then check your logs to see if that's the case.